# issue with using shortcuts in com-visible dll class using C# and Lotus Notes

Tags: c#, com, lotus-notes, ole, lotusscript

I have the purpose to create a com-visible class with UI elements which I can execute/access via Lotus Notes. This is no problem using Visual Studio 2017. My com-visible class is correctly registered in Windows GAC and I'm able to call the available/visible functions supplied by a com-visible class:

```
[Guid("AD2C59FF-7B27-458E-9745-CB27092BAC9E")]
[ClassInterface(ClassInterfaceType.None)]
public class LotusNotesIntegrator
{
    public void OpenDocumentUI(string filePath, string label, string password)
    {
        try
        {
           SingeltonUtils.Instance.MainForm.Show();
        }
        catch (Exception exception)
        {

            throw;
        }
    }

    public void SetFocus()
    {

    }
}
```

I get in trouble when it comes down to usability for the user. Lotus Notes always 'steals' the shortcuts when I'm inside of the UI of my C# com-visible dll which displays a form with a simple text box. As soon as I try to copy the input text of the text box using 'Crtl + C' the shortcut is executed in the underlaying Lotus Notes client. This is a strange behavior as the UI of the com-visible dll is currently with focus and I'm able to type into the textbox field right after the form.Show() method was executed. But the shortcuts are still referenced to the Lotus Notes client which is the host/origin of the com-visible dll.

Has anyone of you experience a similar or the same issue? I hope you guys have an idea or solution for this problem.

Thanks in advance for your effort!

// Martin

Comment: This is a pretty fundamental issue with a GUI app that has its own message dispatcher.  It is no longer the winforms dispatcher that can do its job, it is now done by Notes.  And it will see the keys you press before Winforms can see them.  Ctrl+C is unfortunate, but Notes tends to be unfortunate.  ShowDialog() is required to get the winforms dispatcher back.

Comment: Deleted post from the OP said: "Thank you for the detailed answer. This was the solution!"